# ContextMenu doesn't show up

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have this method:

```
void showAllSongsMenu() {
    if (rebuilding) {
        Toast.makeText(MusicPlayerActivity.this,
                "Database rebuild in progress, please wait!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.allsongs_list,
            null);
    allSongs = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, true);
    Button allSongsMenu = (Button) allSongs.getContentView().findViewById(
            R.id.close_all_songs_menu);
    allSongs.setBackgroundDrawable(MusicPlayerActivity.this.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.unknown_artist));
    allSongs.setFocusable(true);
    allSongsMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            allSongs.dismiss();
        }

    });
    ListView lv = (ListView) allSongs.getContentView().findViewById(
            R.id.all_songs_list);
    //registerForContextMenu(lv);
    lv.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Song options");
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "enqueue song");
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "song info");
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "cancel action");
        }});
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            currentTrack = arg2;
            loadTrack();
            if (isTuning)
                if (track != null)
                    track.pause();
            isTuning = true;
            btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            playTrack();
            allSongs.dismiss();
        }

    });
    base.getAllData();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.simple_row, base.getNames());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    allSongs.showAtLocation(trackInfo, Gravity.CENTER, 0, -30);
}
```

ContextMenu is not shown. I also have onContextItemSelected implemented but it doesn't work since menu is not shown. This method is called whenever i need this PopupWindow, and it is called from OptionsMenu as one of options. I also tried to register listview for context menu events without listener but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you have to register your listview for context menu with

```
registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

which you commented out

### edit:

you are also missing code for opening context menu:

```
openContextMenu(view);
```

which should be placed on some event e.g. button click

### edit2:

you can actually start one dialogfragment from another dialog fragment which would ease your coding. Example is below:

activity code:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Test1().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"bla");
            }
        });
        setContentView(button);
    }

}
```

first dialog fragment:

```
public class Test1 extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        button.setText("test1");
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Test2().show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"bla");
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

}
```

second dialog fragment:

```
public class Test2 extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        button.setText("test2");
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return button;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like for that one to be opened on log press for list item. I will try that now.

Comment: yep this was part of the problem. Now list reacts to event but menu is invisible. What view should i use for context menu showing? Activity or list itself or something third?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with this whole thing is that i want to launch ContextMenu for ListView in PoupWindow. That's what made me problems for me on some other things too. Is there any way for me to show ListView over main window of activity (Or even to switch main view for activity until i have finished wokring with list), and not to use with popup windows?

This is my Dialog

```
package rs.ac.bg.etf.musicplayer.dialogs;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import rs.ac.bg.etf.musicplayer.*;
import rs.ac.bg.etf.musicplayer.database.MusicDatabase;

public class AllSongsDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
MusicPlayerActivity act;
Button cancel;
ListView lv;

public AllSongsDialog(MusicPlayerActivity act) {
    super(act);
    this.act = act;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_allsongs);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close_allsongs_dialog);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.all_songs_list);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos,
                long arg3) {
            act.setCurrentTrack(pos);
            act.loadTrack();
            if (act.isTuning())
                if (act.getTrack() != null)
                    act.getTrack().pause();
            act.setTuning(true);
            act.getBtnPlay().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            act.playTrack();
            dismiss();
        }

    });
    MusicDatabase base = act.getBase();
    base.getAllData();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this.getContext(), R.layout.simple_row, base.getNames());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
    setCancelable(true);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = act.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.context_menu, menu);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.enqueue_song:
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Song enqueued!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return true;
    case R.id.song_info:

        return true;
    case R.id.cancel_menu:
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Well actually if I was you, I would use DialogFragment for this kind of work.

Comment: I used Dialog and it works much better and there is a lot less code, and it is simpler. Only problem now is how to show Dialog over existing Dialog. Do you know how to do it? (Again Context problem i think)

Comment: you can start it normally. as context you can use getActivity() which will give you activity to which dialog is attached to. see edit2 of my post above

Comment: added new code above, when i try to instantiate new Dialog with getContext() i get nothing. (Second case in context menu)

Comment: Dialog and DialogFragment are totally different classes. See my example code in previous post and check documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Oh i didn't know that i will check it out for sure.